# Priority Queue of Objects Giving Wrong Value on One Call of Peek()

Tags: java

So I have this assignment for a Java class, I hit a bit of a road block.  My code is working fine except on the last iteration of a loop, where peek() gives the wrong value.  Every other iteration it gives the correct value, so I am lost as to why it gives the wrong value.

My assignment is to make a priority queue of boxes.  We read float values from a text file, and then fill the boxes with the values.  No box can have a total sum greater than 1.0.

The data from the text file is: 0.1, 0.6, 0.11, 0.765, 0.01, 0.42, 0.1492,0.667, 0.333, 0.111
Code:
 Box Class:

```
public class box implements Comparable<box>
{
//instance variables
private ArrayList<Float> values;    
private Float totalValue=0.0f;  

public box ()
{
    values = new ArrayList<Float>();        
}
public box(Float val)
{
    values = new ArrayList<Float>();
    values.add(val);        
}

//add new values to the box
public void addVal(Float newVal)
{
    values.add(newVal);
}   
/*
 * Adds up all the values in the box, returns sum as Float.
 */
public Float findSum()
{
    totalValue=0.0f;
    for(Float val : values)
    {
        totalValue=totalValue+val;
    }
    return totalValue;      
}
```

}

Code for comparator
        import java.util.Comparator;

```
    public class boxComparator implements Comparator<box>
   {
        //compare method for boxes
        public int compare(box a, box b)
        {   
        if (a.findSum()>b.findSum())
            return 10;
        else if (a.findSum()<b.findSum())
            return -10;
        else
            return 0;   

    }
}
```

Code for PackingBoxes (contains Main):
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class PackBoxes 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
        ...
        boxComparator compSum = new boxComparator();

        ...
     *Strategy A: As each new item is processed, it is placed in the 
     *            fullest box that can hold it. 
     */
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("Packing via most-filled strategy:");
    System.out.println();

    //Create new priorityqueue of boxes for strategy A
    PriorityQueue<box> boxesA = new PriorityQueue<box>(11,compSum);
    //add first box to queue
    boxesA.add(new box());


    //for each loop, goes through arrayList L
    for(Float x : L)
    {       

        //if element + sum of current box is less than 1 put element
        //into the current box

        if(x + boxesA.peek().findSum() <1)
        {               
            boxesA.peek().addVal(x);
        }
        //if element + sum of current box is greater than 1, then make
        // a new box
        else
        {               
            boxesA.add(new box(x));                 
        }

    }
    System.out.println(boxesA.size()+" boxes were used.");


    //print queue
    while(!boxesA.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(boxesA.poll().findSum());
    }


}
```

After much debugging, I've found that the program does the following:
Read 0.1, 0.6, 0.11 put in box 1.  Read .765, does't fit in box 1, create box 2.  Read .01 put in box 2 (which is smallest total sum).  Read 0.42, doesn't fit in box 2, create box 3.  Put .1492 in box 3.  Read .667, create box 4.  Read .333 put in box 3 (box 3 has smallest current sum).  **read .111, doesn't fit in box 3, create box 5**
The bolded part is the problem.  It should read .111 and try and put it into box 4, with .667.  But when I use peek it brings up the box with, 0.42, 0.1492, 0.33, for a total sum of .9022.  Since 0.667 is smaller than 0.9022 I don't understand why peek() isn't giving me box 4.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  Tried to delete code that wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as far as I can tell is that you do not re-order the boxes when you put .333 in box 3. When you do that, box 3 is no longer the least full box - it should no longer be on top of the queue. Box 4 should be moved to the top of the queue. But since box 3 stays on top of the queue, next time you try to insert an item, it looks at box 3 (the top item of the queue). When it fails to insert into box 3, it makes a new box.

To solve this, all you need to do is place a simple sort function for your queue after you add a new value or a new box. That way the box that is the least full will always be on top.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me.  I thought the whole point of a priority queue is that the min value is the head, and when you peek() or poll() you get the min value.  When the program gets to the value 0.333 it puts it inside box 3, and not the current box 4 because box 3 has the lowest sum at the time.  Also at the end I poll() all the boxes and print, and they come out in order, 0.111, 0.667, 0.775, 0.81, 0.9022.  The only time the current box stays on top of the queue is the last iteration of that loop.

Comment: You are right - the priority queue will sort itself. However, are you sure it sorts itself any time you modify any one of its items? As a simple test, try this. Instead of simply adding the new value to the box, remove the box from the queue, add the item to the box, and then put the box back in the queue. I will bet that it works.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you very much, you're a total life savor.  So apparently modifying an item in the queue is not enough to get it to update, the queue needs to be modified.  Not only did you help me with my assignment, but more importantly I understand better how the priority queue collection works.  Thank you again.

Comment: @SysKonfig No problem, happy to help